# How to test reference equality in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing references to various objects.
The only guarantee I have is that the array does not contain multiple references to the same object.
Specifically, I am **not** guaranteed that the objects' *contents* are different.

There is another piece of code which gives me a reference to some object, `obj`.
I need to test if `obj` is the last item in my array, and if this is true, and `obj` satisfies some additional requirements, I want to call `pop` on my array.

How do I test if `obj` was the last item in my array?

Comment: It's well described in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators): *"Equal (`==`): [...] If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory."*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In JavaScript, `===` (and, actually, `==`) with object references tests reference equality (e.g., that they refer to the **same** object).

So to handle the requirement

> There is another piece of code which gives me a reference to some object, obj.
>   I need to test if obj is the last item in my array

...then:

```
if (obj === array[array.length-1]) {
    // It's the same object
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks, I feel so stupid. :-) Didn't realize `===` has different behavior for objects than strings.

Comment: @Mehrdad: No need, we are all seekers of knowledge. *(He said gnomically.)*